# How to control a system when not all inputs are "changeable"

Tags: control-theory, linear-control

I am designing a PI controller for an electrical system consisting of several parallel-connected branches, where each branch current will be controlled by a converter.

\begin{equation}\label{eq:current_dynamics}
    \begin{split}
        \frac{d}{dt}I_k=\frac{1}{\left(L_{line}-L\right)}&\left[-R_{line}I_k+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\pi}A_fV_{m_k}\right.\\
        &+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\pi}A_dV_{m_k}\cos(\alpha_k)-V_{DC_y}^{*}\\
        &\left.-\sum_{j\neq k}\left(R_{line}I_j+L_{line}\frac{d}{dt}I_j\right)\right]\quad k\in[1,N]
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

Where $I_k$ and $I_j$ are my currents (states), $V_{m_k}$ are voltage sources that I do not control (their value may change regardless of my will) and $\alpha_k$ are my thyristor firing angles, the only variables that I can to use to control my system. The voltage source $V_{DC_y}^{*}$ is much more of a fixed input to the system, so can be considered as constant. All other parameters such as $L$, $R_{line}$ and $L_{line}$ are constants.

I have here some questions:

1. My first attempt was defining:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \mathbf{x}&=\left[I_1\quad I_2\quad\cdots\quad I_N\right]^{T} \in\mathbb{R}^{N}\\
        \mathbf{d}&=\left[V_{m_1}\quad V_{m_2}\quad\cdots\quad V_{m_N}\quad V_{DC_y}^{*}\right]^{T}\in\mathbb{R}^{N+1}\\
        \mathbf{u}&=\left[\alpha_1\quad \alpha_2\quad\cdots\quad \alpha_N\right]^{T}\in\mathbb{R}^{N}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

Then, I have coupling not only by other other states, but also by their derivatives. Also, I have a nonlinearity where I have $V_{m_k}\cos(\alpha_k)$. So what I did was to define:

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{h}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{d})=\frac{1}{\left(L_{line}-L\right)}\begin{bmatrix}\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\pi}A_fV_{m_1}+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\pi}A_dV_{m_1}\cos(\alpha_1)-V_{DC_y}^{*}\\
    \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\pi}A_fV_{m_2}+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\pi}A_dV_{m_2}\cos(\alpha_2)-V_{DC_y}^{*}\\
    \vdots\\
    \frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\pi}A_fV_{m_N}+\frac{3\sqrt{3}}{\pi}A_dV_{m_N}\cos(\alpha_N)-V_{DC_y}^{*}\end{bmatrix}
\end{equation}

And rewrite the equation as:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \frac{d}{dt}x_k+\frac{L_{line}}{\left(L_{line}-L\right)}\sum_{j\neq k}\frac{d}{dt}x_j=\frac{1}{\left(L_{line}-L\right)}&\left[-R_{line}x_k-\sum_{j\neq k}R_{line}x_j\right]+h_k
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

From which I get the following nonlinear model:

\begin{equation}
    \mathbf{E}\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{A}\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{h}(\mathbf{u},\mathbf{d})
\end{equation}

If I go through withe linearization, I can obtain the following:

\begin{equation}
    \delta\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{E}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\delta\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{E}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\delta\mathbf{u}+\mathbf{E}^{-1}\mathbf{G}\delta\mathbf{d}
\end{equation}

**How do I design a PI controller from this?** Should I treat $\mathbf{u}$ as a disturbance vector? What would be the procedure?

2. The second attempt was defining:

\begin{equation}
    \begin{split}
        \mathbf{x}&=\left[I_1\quad I_2\quad\cdots\quad I_N\right]^{T} \in\mathbb{R}^{N}\\
        \mathbf{u}&=\left[V_{DC_y}^{*} \quad V_{m_1}\quad V_{m_2}\quad\cdots\quad V_{m_N}\quad \alpha_1\quad \alpha_2\quad\cdots\quad \alpha_N \right]^{T}\in\mathbb{R}^{2N+1}
    \end{split}
\end{equation}

which basically means that I put all the system inputs, whether I can manipulate them or not, into vector $\mathbf{u}$.

Following the same procedure gives me in the end:

\begin{equation}
    \delta\dot{\mathbf{x}}=\mathbf{E}^{-1}\mathbf{A}\delta\mathbf{x}+\mathbf{E}^{-1}\mathbf{B}\delta\mathbf{u}
\end{equation}

Which is the classical state-space representation, but now I have an input vector $\mathbf{u}$ that comprises both inputs that I can and cannot manipulate.

**How should I deal with this?** I want a PI control that generates the $\alpha$ firing angles such that the currents $I_k$ follow $I_k^{*}$ reference values.

Thank you!

Comment: Do you only want to limit the controller to a PI, or would a nonlinear controller such as input to state linearization also be an option?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen The idea in this problem is to limit to a PI... I simulated with a hand-tuned PI and the system works very well :)

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen also, it would be very nice and useful for me to understand the procedure for this problem, as independent voltage sources are very common as inputs to power electronics systems.

Comment: Do you know some bounds on $V_{m_k}$ and how fast those typically change over time?

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen I do have both upper and lower bounds on $V_{m_k}$. Their rate of change, however, are not modeled in this work. These are peak voltage outputs of wind turbine generators, so it can be pretty stochastic.

Comment: @KwinvanderVeen Also, my idea here was to come up with a PI controller that can be placed independently at each converter. This means that in order to converter 1 to control $I_1$, it will only use feedback (will only take measurements) from $I_1$.

Comment: The notation is a bit misleading. Usually you collect all inputs that you can control in the $u$ vector and all inputs that you cannot control in the $d$ vector and treat them as disturbances. So I suggest you have $u = \begin{bmatrix} \alpha_1 & \alpha_2 & \dots & \alpha_N \end{bmatrix}^T$ and $d = \begin{bmatrix} V_{DC_y}^* & V_{m_1} & V_{m_2} & \dots & V_{m_N} \end{bmatrix}^T$. Now, you can design PI controllers for $u$, that reject disturbances $d$.

Comment: First of all you should definitely change the model to what @SampleTime suggests. This model looks like a consensus problem (with a complete graph). It should easily separate into individual nodes after some manipulation so you can focus only on controlling one first-order system while guaranteeing all nodes approach to same states, i.e. consensus.